# How to keep Linux kernel responsive while having high memory usage?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, kill, ubuntu-14.04

Sometimes I have a lot of programs running and despite of <del>16GB</del> 8GB of memory my ubuntu linux 14.04 LTS turns out to be not responsive at all. I won't be able to get a TTY to kill some processes to release some memory.
I know that kernel will kill some processes and release memory but it turns out to be too late for me and I want to have control over my machine at any time (after all it is Linux and of course I want control!)

So, how I can change my machines configurations and reserve required resources in such a way that I can always access terminal?

**Update, more info about my system**

```
mehdix@spielplatz:~$ uname -a
Linux spielplatz 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

mehdix@spielplatz:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

mehdix@spielplatz:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       50264964  20127112  27561460  43% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             3981612        12   3981600   1% /dev
tmpfs             799284      1404    797880   1% /run
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3996412     45884   3950528   2% /run/shm
none              102400        56    102344   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5      201454556 171984664  19213512  90% /home
```

**Update, memory is 8GB not 16, sorry for that**

```
mehdix@spielplatz:~$ cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:        7992824 kB
MemFree:         2476728 kB
Buffers:          250048 kB
Cached:          1902116 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          3680264 kB
Inactive:        1416088 kB
Active(anon):    2947240 kB
Inactive(anon):   602320 kB
Active(file):     733024 kB
Inactive(file):   813768 kB
Unevictable:        2336 kB
Mlocked:            2336 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               160 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2946576 kB
Mapped:           463512 kB
Shmem:            605372 kB
Slab:             247452 kB
SReclaimable:     198912 kB
SUnreclaim:        48540 kB
KernelStack:        5784 kB
PageTables:        61804 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3996412 kB
Committed_AS:    9664312 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      418404 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359276328 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    827392 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      185084 kB
DirectMap2M:     8017920 kB
```

Comment: Did you install the Server or Desktop (preemptive kernel) version of Ubuntu?  Post the output of the `uname -a` command.

Comment: You should monitor your system to understand if some process is leaking memory. Also maybe try to change a bit the vm.swapîness to see if it brings some improvement (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness)

Comment: Are you certain all 16 GB is available? Is your / or a separate /tmp is filling up? Is there some free (fast storage) space to add more swap? These could be some quick look-at options, but a lot depends on each. The kernel should not exhaust ALL pysical RAM before start swapping, but if some part of your file system capped free storage user space will at least bog down, or maybe the entire system crashes. I run 16 GB on Debian 64amd xfce with 4x4GB swap across a 1TB drive and for my use that is a LOT of capacity.

Comment: @sawdust I have updated the answer with uname -a output. I use desktop version.

Comment: @tonioc Non-responsiveness always happens for me when I have a lot of tabs open in chrome browser. I go to try swappiness. So far I learned there is a kernel arg called 'zswap' which I enabled it to see how things change.

Comment: @arch-abit My apologized for wrong initial info. My RAM is 8GB not 16GB. I add output of df command. When I have chrome, pycharm and some other applications open and I try to open an memory hungry website system always gets not-responsive and I have to force restart it.

Comment: Yes, you need to add some swap. 8 GB is still a lot, and with some swap added that should be enough for a LOT of browser tabs :)